# cannot launch node of type

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros indigo. ubuntu 14.04 trusty.

this is the launch xml file commandclient.launch :

```
<launch>

<!-- Start the command action client to take commands -->
  <node name="command_action_client"  pkg="hal_main" type="commandclient"  output="screen" > 
  </node>
  
</launch>
```

roslaunch hal_main commandclient.launch :

```
... logging to /home/jaysin/.ros/log/be04aa0e-5080-11e4-ab58-28e347742258/roslaunch-jaysin-24849.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://jaysin:60903/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.9

NODES
  /
    command_action_client (hal_main/commandclient)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hal_main/commandclient]: can't locate node [commandclient] in package [hal_main]
No processes to monitor
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

rosrun hal_main commandclient:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named commandclient below /home/jaysin/ros/clam3/src/hal_main
```

rospack find hal_main :

```
/home/jaysin/ros/clam3/src/hal_main
```

echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH :

```
/home/jaysin/ros/clam3/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

launches from other packages work fine. i have rebuilt everything after deleting devel and build.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194708/cannot-launch-node-of-type/) by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

silly mistake in cmakelists.txt. :

```
add_executable(command_action_client src/commandclient.cpp)
```

instead off :

```
add_executable(commandclient src/commandclient.cpp)
```

---

Originally posted by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) with karma: 259 on 2014-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0